# If $f(x)=x^{2021},$ Find $f^{(2022)}(x)=?$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Problem:**

If there is a function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=x^{2021}$, find the two thousand and twenty-second derivative of $f(x)$, i.e. $f^{(2022)}(x)$.

**Working by Myself:**

I know the fact that the $2022$th derivative of something is going to be itself, but I don't know where to go from here.

**Working by User Cheese Cake From Edit:**

To help improve this question, I have included some help of my own. Unfortunately, I could not find background information for this problem, but it is most probably just of interest to the original poster.

First, I guess we can find $f^\prime(x)$, which is $2022x^{2021}$, and $f''(x)$, which is $2022\times 2021 x^{2020}$.

We can see that $f^{(2022)}(x)$ is $2022\times2021\times2020\times\dots\times1 x^0$, which is $2022!$.

If this question is revived, I will remove  a certain section of this section, and post my answer here.

Comment: Hint: try smaller cases, and it'll be incredibly clear. (Maybe the case $g(x) = x^3,$ and find $g^{(4)}(x)$.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that it is not generally true that the $2022^{nd}$ derivative of something is going to be itself.

Comment: Is $f^{2022}$ meant to be the 2022nd derivative? If so, that is usually written as $f^{(2022)}$ to distinguish it between other meanings for $f^{2022}.$

Comment: "I know for a fact..." Well, that isn't true, as written. What do you mean "is going to be itself?"

Comment: Prove or use the fact that $n$-th derivative of polynomial of degree $m$ is polynomial of degree $m-n$ at $m\geq n$ or is zero at $m < n$.

Answer (score -2):

**Original Problem's Solution:**

Using the formula $\frac{d}{dx}(x^n)=nx^{n-1}$, we know that

\begin{align}
f^{(1)}(x)&=2021x^{2021-1}=2021x^{2020}\\
f^{(2)}(x)&=2021\times f^{(1)}(x^{2020})=2021\times2020x^{2019}\\
f^{(3)}(x)&=2021\times2020\times f^{(1)}(x^{2019})=2021\times2020\times2019x^{2018}\\
\text{etc}\\
f^{(2022)}(x)&=2021\times2020\times2019\times\dots\times0\times f^{(1)}(x^{-1})\\
&=0
\end{align}

**Generalisation:**

We can easily prove that $f^{(n)}(x^{n-1})=0$ as well, because the degree of the derivative is one higher than the degree of the function, which would result in

\begin{align}
f^{(n-1)}(x^{n-1})&=(n-1)! \times f^{(1)}(x^0)=(n-1)!\times0=0\\
f^{(n)}(x^{n-1})&=0\times f^{(1)}(x^{-1})=0 
\end{align}

Comment: $f(x)=x^{2021}$, not $x^{2022}$. Now it's even easier!

Comment: So would this mean that if f(x)=x^2021, then f^(2022)(x) = 2021!? Or would it be equal to 0 since 2022>2021?

Comment: Yes, the answer is zero. I fixed the solution

Comment: @TonyK I know it has been a long time, but since I have edited my answer, could you please reverse the downvote? Thanks!

Comment: @CheeseCake: I didn't downvote.

Comment: @TonyK Sorry, nevermind. Anyway, do you think the solution is correct now?